# Atribuir novos itens em um array sem reescrever o código todo

Tags: php, array, libcurl, cookies

Existe alguma maneira de adicionar novos items sem reescrever o código ?

Veja: Se existir cookies então utilizo `CURLOPT_COOKIE` Se não, não utilizo:

```
if ($cookies) {
            $options = [
                CURLOPT_URL             => $url,
                CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST   => 'GET',
                CURLOPT_HEADER          => true,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => false,
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  => false,
                CURLOPT_COOKIE          => implode('; ', $cookies),
                CURLOPT_USERAGENT       => $this->ua
            ];
        } else {
            $options = [
                CURLOPT_URL             => $url,
                CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST   => 'GET',
                CURLOPT_HEADER          => true,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => false,
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  => false,
                CURLOPT_USERAGENT       => $this->ua
            ];
        }
```

Comment: Adicionar novos items ao array $options?

Comment: isso mesmo. @TaffarelXavier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se for o que entendi, que é adicionar dados ao array, você pode:

```php
//Adiciona um valor ao array com a chave `CURLOPT_OTHER`
 $options['CURLOPT_OTHER'] = 'OUTRO VALOR';
```

Se quiser adicionar como se fosse o push, faça o seguinte:

```
$options[] = 'OUTRO VALOR';
```

> **Para ficar mais legível, você pode fazer o seguinte:**

```
$url = "myUrl";

$options = [
                CURLOPT_URL             => $url,
                CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST   => 'GET',
                CURLOPT_HEADER          => true,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => false,
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  => false,
                CURLOPT_USERAGENT       => "agent"
            ];
//Se existir, então adiciona ao array a chave `CURLOPT_COOKIE` com o valor $cookie
if ($_COOKIE) {
      $options[CURLOPT_COOKIE] = implode('; ', $_COOKIE);
}

var_dump($options);
```

**REFERÊNCIA:**

https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.types.array.php

Comment: Criou dois arrays no final do array ficou assim: `19914 => 
    array (size=1)
      10022 => string` é normal isso ?

Comment: Na verdade, mostrei duas formas de adicionar dados a um array. O famoso `push`.

Comment: Veja a edição...

Comment: Por que usaste as constantes pré-definidas de `curl`? https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/curl.constants.php. Elas retornam números, por isso 19914, 10022; por exemplo a constante `CURLOPT_URL`  retorna `10002`.

Comment: Exatamente, elas retornam numeros, mas nunca ordenados... porem foi resolvido obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Considere ter sempre a chave, mas com valor vazio se não houver cookies. Não sei se eu usaria as constantes do cURL pra indexar a array, mas vou deixar como você fez. Ficaria assim:

```
$options = [
    CURLOPT_URL             => $url,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST   => 'GET',
    CURLOPT_HEADER          => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  => false,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT       => "agent",
    CURLOPT_COOKIE          => empty($cookies) ? null : implode('; ', $cookies)
];
```

Comment: Você faria de que forma ?

Comment: Talvez até do seu jeito. Mais importante que a forma escolhida é entender a diferença entre usar `CURLOPT_COOKIE` e `'CURLOPT_COOKIE'` como chave. A primeira na verdade é uma constante que contém um número. A segunda é uma string.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar da função array merge para isso, da seguinte forma:

```
$options = [
    CURLOPT_URL             => $url,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST   => 'GET',
    CURLOPT_HEADER          => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER  => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST  => false,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT       => $this->ua
];

if ($cookies) {
    $options = array_merge($options, [
            CURLOPT_COOKIE =>implode('; ', $cookies)
        ]
    )
}
```

Dessa forma ele adicionará ao array de opções apenas o parametro do cookie

Comment: Não funcionou. Ele transformou o valor do código da constante em um indice ordenado

Comment: `$options[CURLOPT_COOKIE] = implode...` dentro do if bastaria, não?